# html text Extraction in j2me

Tags: html, java-me, lwuit

I want to extract text from a web page in j2me, I have used String operations,but I am not getting the result, was my code correct?

**The String from a web page:**

```
<td align="left" valign="middle"  class="celebrity-details-description-txt" > 

<p style="text-align: justify;">

 Hero Gopichand's new movie under the direction of Chandrasekhar Yeleti is progressing at brisk pace in Ladakh. Recently, the unit has shot an extensive action scene on Gopichand, Taapsee and others under Buzkashi sport backdrop. alt="Buzkashi sport, gopichand buzkashi, gopichand new movie, buzkashi afghanisthan sport

</p> 

<p style="text-align: justify;">&nbsp;</p> <p style="text-align: justify;">&nbsp;</p>

</td>
```

Here my CODE:

```
int tdIndex = readUrl.indexOf("<td align=\"left\" valign=\"middle\" class=\"celebrity-details-description-txt\">");
tdIndex = readUrl.indexOf(">", tdIndex);
int endtdIndex = readUrl.indexOf("</td>", tdIndex);
String content = readUrl.substring(tdIndex + 1, endtdIndex);
```

Comment: can any one revise my question?html tags are not visible?

Comment: i am getting html page source in place of  String content ,other than that whole String

Comment: your code is correct. What values are you getting in both tdIndex and endtdIndex?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like in `readUrl` String there is an extra space between `middle` and `class` on the `td`. My suggestion is to change

```
int tdIndex = readUrl.indexOf("&lt;td align=\"left\" valign=\"middle\" class=\"celebrity-details-description-txt\">");
```

to just

```
int tdIndex = readUrl.indexOf("class=\"celebrity-details-description-txt\"");
```