# extract text from HTML textbox using j2me

Tags: html, java-me, html-parsing

i know this question might sound silly but is there a way to extract text from HTML textbox using `j2me`.

Comment: Check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12107974/html-text-extraction-in-j2me?rq=1

Comment: thanks.. but will it work for dynamic webpages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a Java HTML DOM Parser library. I Recommend **[jsoup: Java HTML Parser](http://jsoup.org/)**.

Download the Library file from **[here](http://jsoup.org/download)**.
Documentation is located **[here](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/introduction/parsing-a-document)**.